# Rhythm Box Cuts out!

Tags: music

So i installed ubuntu "Trusty Tahr" today Works like a charm BUT my only problem is the Rhythm Box thing Works ok but the music cuts out and it happens like 4~5 times a song and it is basically like the song pauses and plays instantly and it doesn't please me in music playing so if there is any other music players better than rhythm box player i would gladly use it

Comment: Ok so i downloaded Clementine , it's better but still it cuts out at random intervals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Ubuntu can't recognize your audio driver. We can follow these steps :

**1)** Go to terminal and type that code : `aplay -l`

If code plays **succesfully** you get your all soundcard driver installed already in your computer. If you get an **error** you will get an error message like this:

```
aplay: device_list:221: no soundcard found...
```

If you get an error please follow me :-)

**2)** Type : `lspci -v`

**Success** : At this point, you should see your sound card listed. This is a positive sign because it means that Ubuntu is detecting the presence of your soundcard, but the drivers are not installed/running. Leave your shell running since you will need it.

**Error** :

- If it is not listed, then there are a few things that you can do.
  If your soundcard is an onboard sound card, then it might be disabled in the system's BIOS. You will have to reboot and hit the key that lets you enter into the BIOS (usually Delete, F2, or F8).
- If your soundcard is not onboard, make sure that it is properly
  seated in the PCI slot. If your card is working under Windows then
  this is not a problem.

**3)** Check to see if the ALSA driver for your sound card exists. Go to http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/ and search for your sound card (chipset) manufacturer in the dropdown box. You'll be given a matrix of the sound cards made by the manufacturer. Try to match the chipset you found in step 2 with the driver(green hyperlink text).

**Success** - You will have found the driver for your soundcard's chipset.
**Failure** - You will have not found the driver for your soundcard chipset. (at the moment I cannot help you, but stay tuned!)

**4)** Now go to the terminal and type that `sudo modprobe snd-`

Now, press the TAB key BEFORE pressing the ENTER key to see a list of modules. Try to find the module that matches the driver you found in step 3.

Comment: well i dont really know how to add a code so ill just paste it here :P **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC888 Analog [ALC888 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: ALC888 Digital [ALC888 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: CS4281 [Cirrus Logic CS4281], device 0: CS4281 [CS4281]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
that's what i got

Comment: Then you got your audio drivers. Maybe you should try to use VLC Media or [Audacious](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/audacious).. Because I remembered that I had same problem when I installed Ubuntu 12.04 first and I removed Ubuntu's media player.

Comment: Or you could follow these steps and jump into more Ubuntu : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=205449 :-)

Comment: i uninstalled Rhythm box and downloaded Audacious , works like a charm Thanks! :D